# Python 2.7 - Call Main recursivelly

Tags: python-2.7

I have a Python module that takes in 2 Args (an input config file and an output file). I call the main function in the standard way at the end of the module.

```
# Call to main function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On a certain time condition in the logic at the end of the main function (Processing time < Current Time - 20 minutes), I have a need to process main function again until processing time is within 20 minutes of current time.

Given the arguments passed to the module, do I have to do anything special or 
is it as simple as I have this if statement at the end of the main

```
if (time delta condition):
     main()
else:
     sys.exit()
```

I'm assuming the module main call above would still need to be there to invoke the module from Cron.

Please advise. I need the main to process `argv[1]` and `[2]` whenever it is called.

Regards
Siva

Comment: I believe that the answer is "Yes." It's as simple as what you suggest. Have you tried it?

Comment: It worked. Thanks smarx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally recursion is not a great method of flow control. For one thing, you may need to pay attention to what happens if your recursive call `return`s (though you seem to be working around this by calling `sys.exit()` in the non-recursive case).

It might make more sense to use a `while` loop instead. Something like:

```
def main():
    while some_condition():
        do_stuff()
```

Obviously you'll need replace the function calls I'm making with the actual details of your problem.

If the condition might not be true at the start, but you want to run the loop body at least once anyway, it might make sense to do the actual condition check at the end of the loop body, and save the result in a variable:

```
def main():
    keep_running = True
    while keep_running:
        do_stuff()
        keep_running = some_condition()
```

You can also use `while True` and `break` out of the loop if the conditions indicate it's appropriate at some point (which could be in the middle of the loop body):

```
def main():
    while True:
        do_stuff()
        if exit_condition():
            break
        do_other_stuff()
```

Comment: Great way to do it more efficiently. Thanks Blcknght for taking the time to explain this.